# playframework : How do I use a constant class in html template?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a constant class looks like this:

```
class ConstantUtil {
  public static final A = "XXX";
  public static final B = "YYY";
}
```

Now , I would like to use this class in my template, e.g. `ConstantUtil.A`, is there any syntax to make it in play ?

Answer (score 3):

You just have to call it like you would normally do anywhere else.

```
@ConstantUtil.A
```

Be sure ti import the proper package.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, I need to use it in Play's template.

Comment: I didn't realize you where using play 1. sry

Answer (score 1):

Just use `${full.path.Constant.A}` in template.